# Como usar subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

no se si hay alguna manera de capturar lo que salga en la cmd,e intentado hacer esto,me muestra la información pero no genera el archivo y me lanza este error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "comandos.py", line 5, in <module>
>     datos=info.readlines()
> AttributeError: 'CompletedProcess' object has no attribute 'readlines'
> ```

Este es el código:

```
import subprocess 
comando=("ipconfig")
info=subprocess.run((comando),shell=True)
datos=info.readlines()
fichero=open("datos", "w")
fichero.writelines(info)
fichero.close()
print("El nombre del fichero es datos")
```

Comment: si,es es lo que quiero hacer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que redirigir la salida estándar de forma adecuada. Si solo quieres guardarla en un archivo puedes redirigirla directamente

```
import subprocess


with open("datos.txt", 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.run(['ipconfig'], stdout=f, shell = True)
```

Si quieres guardarla en un string para imprimirla o cualquier otra cosa, puedes redirigir la salida usando pilelines

```
import subprocess


p = subprocess.run(['ipconfig'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
out = p.stdout
print(out.decode("cp850"))
with open("datos.txt", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

En Python > 3.6 se puede definir el encoding adecuado con el parámetro `encoding` de `subprocess.run`, por lo que es posible hacer

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.run(['ipconfig'],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   shell = True,
                   universal_newlines = True,
                   encoding = "cp850")
out = p.stdout
print(out)
with open("datos.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

`universal_newlines=True` usa el valor retornado por `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` para codificar el string. El problema es que Windows en este caso trabaja con los mapas de caracteres tradicionales de DOS, para Español debe ser CP850 y no con los propios de aplicaciones como es CP1252.

Podemos guardar sin problemas la salida usando `bytes` y luego leer el archivo con la codificación adecuada. Para imprimir el archivo sin problemas si necesitamos especificar la codificación adecuada.

> En los ejemplos se asume codificación "cp850" por defecto para la terminal. Cambiar si es necesario. Se puede comprobar, abriendo CMD e ingresando `chcp`.

**Edición:**

`universal_newlines=True` retorna la salida como texto, independientemente de la codificación para definir la nueva linea que se use (`\n` en UNIX, `\r\n` en Windows, `\r` en OS hasta versión 9, etc ). Para ello usa el encoding retornado por `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` para decodificar la salida. El problema es que esto no retornará el encoding por defecto real de CMD que sera usado para retornar la salida de `ipconfig`. Por eso es recomendable evitarlo y trabajar directamente con bytes.

`stdout` es la salida estándar(standard output) que por norma general será la consola/terminal. En este caso, a grandes rasgos, redirigimos esta salida para que en vez de a la consola se dirija a un string  o a un fichero.

Comment: me podrias explicar para que sirbe: stdout y universal_newlines

Comment: @Snake he editado la pregunta. He modificado un poco lo anterior (además de intentar aclarar estas dudas).  Es posible que con el código anterior las tildes no se imprimieran correctamente. Fue error mio por estar acostumbrado a trabajar en sistemas *nix con UTF-8 como codificación en la terminal...